# Changing sequence of columns

Tags: python, awk

I need to change the sequence of the columns (i.e. order)

```
# cat customer.csv
customerno, firstname, lastname, sales
23242, john, doe, 2345.00
23253, jane, doe, 1234.00
23221, greg, johnson, 2345.00
23210, howard, gardner, 2345.00
```

This works, but there is no comma after first column.

```
# awk  '{print $4, $3, $2, $1}' customer.csv
sales lastname, firstname, customerno,
2345.00 doe, john, 23242,
1234.00 doe, jane, 23253,
2345.00 johnson, greg, 23221,
2345.00 gardner, howard, 23210,
```

How do I remove the comma at the end? Is there an elegant way of doing this?

```
# awk  '{print $4 ",", $3, $2, $1}' customer.csv
sales, lastname, firstname, customerno,
2345.00, doe, john, 23242,
1234.00, doe, jane, 23253,
2345.00, johnson, greg, 23221,
2345.00, gardner, howard, 23210,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you just forgot to set your field separators:

```
$ awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {print $4, $3, $2, $1}' customer.csv
sales, lastname, firstname, customerno
2345.00, doe, john, 23242
1234.00, doe, jane, 23253
2345.00, johnson, greg, 23221
2345.00, gardner, howard, 23210
```

Answer (score 2):

use comma + space as delimiter and print the necessary commas while printing the columns:

```
awk -F", " '{print $4",", $3",", $2",", $1}' filename
```

Comment: Use FS instead of `",",` ----   `awk -F ", " '{ print $4 FS $3 FS $2 FS $1 }' customer.csv`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in python (which your tagging would suggest), try the following:

```
f = open('customer.csv')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(', ')
    line.reverse()
    print ', '.join(line)
```

Or, if you want to output the result to a file:

```
f = open('customer.csv')
out = ''
for line in f:
    line = line.strip().split(', ')
    line.reverse()
    out += ', '.join(line) + '\n'
f.close()

f = open('customer2.csv', 'w')
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{sub(",",""); print $4", " $3, $2, $1}' file
```